# Vertical data selection in MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, entity-attribute-value

If I have a table like this:

```
ID color size weight
1  red   2    3
2  green 4    5
```

So to run a mysql query to find the `ID` number that is `color:red` and `size:2` and `weight:3` I can do this:

```
select ID from table where color=red AND size=2 AND weight=3
```

As properties are growing in addition to color, weight, size, mileage, speed, etc... and I want to keep the table scaling it would make sense to organize it this way

```
ID  ID2  property  value
1   1    color     red
2   1    size      2
3   1    weight    3
4   2    color     green
5   2    size      4
6   2    weight    5
```

How do I run a select query here to find the `ID` number that is `color:red` and `size:2` and `weight:3`

Should I create a bunch of self joins like suggested here:

```
select t.id2 
from test t
join test t1 on(t.id = t1.ID2)
join test t2 on(t.id = t2.ID2)
where t.property = 'color'
and t1.property = 'size'
and t2.property = 'weight'
and t.value = 'red'
and t1.value = '2'
and t2.value = '3'
```

or should I just grab all the `ID2`s from the database and sort through in with PHP?

Or is there any other way to select the data from the table?

I am looking at 10,000 IDs and about 200 properties that will very slowly grow in number.

Comment: This is known as an Entity Attribute Value model (EAV). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model. There are lots of opinions out there as to good/bad (eg https://sqlblog.org/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway), but from experience of using one I'll say that querying is more complex, generally slower, and you pretty much lose all referential integrity. Read the articles and make your decision being aware of the pros and cons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way to get the desired result set if you are not going to use bunch of self joins then you can use `in(),count(distinct) and group by` and i assume for each `id2` you have unique properties

```
select t.id2 
from test t
where t.property in('color','size','weight')
and t.value in('red','2','3')
group by t.id2 
having count(distinct t.property) = 3
```

Above query will look for `property` column for provided values and count with distinct = 3 part will ensure for all the provided key/value pair to match,So if your properties grow from 3 then you have to provide the no. which will be equal to the no. of properties to match i.e for case `t.property in('color','size','weight','test')` the count part will change to `having count(distinct t.property) = 4`

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06574d/8)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure I understand what you want to do, but I'll give it a try.

As a general rule: Never get data you do not need from your DB. Do not select more than you need and discard results in your code.

What seems to make sense (from what I understand) is to split your table in 2. One specifying your items, and one specifying their properties:

*item table (items)*

```
ID name
1  item 1
2  item 2
```

*prop table (props)*

```
itemID name  value
1       color red
1       size  2
2       color blue
2       size  3
```

To get all the blue items of size 2, you can run a query of the form:

```
Select name
  from items
  join props as colors on items.id = colors.itemId
  join props as sizes on items.id = sizes.itemId
  where (colors.name = 'color' and colors.value = 'blue')
    and (sizes.name = 'size' and sizes.value = '2')
```

Comment: I think I got this far, the problem I am having is how to run a query efficiently. For example I want to select all the items that are color:red and the size:5. Your query would probably pick up item 1 even though its incorrect because it has size:2.

Comment: nope, it would return items which answer to all conditions (note the "and" keyword).